# How to save ImageProvider<object> image file to Gallery?

Tags: flutter

I want to save the `ImageProvider<Object>` file that I received from `arSessionManager.snapshot()` to my gallery.

However, `ImageGallerySaver.saveImage()` can only use `Uint8List` image.

What should I do?

This is my code.

```
Future<void> onTakeScreenshot() async {
    ImageProvider<Object> capture = await arSessionManager.snapshot();
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => Dialog(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(image: capture, fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        ),
      ),
    );
    await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(capture); // the problematic part
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be the following:

```dart
await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage((capture as MemoryImage).bytes);
```